# how to solve this Chosekijio sangaku with three equilateral triangles and three circles?

Tags: sangaku

please, how to solve this  particularsangaku?[image]

Here, sun is a japanese measure unity.
[image]

sangakus are part of the japanese tradition and are of interest of math problem solvers and enhusiasts and i've not found a solution, the sangaku is  taken from this PhD Thesis:https://www.academia.edu/30061089/_PhD_Thesis_Sangaku_A_Mathematical_Artistic_Religious_and_Diagrammatic_Examination.

this particular sangaku is important for me because this it is a sangaku with a photograph presenting typical sangakus sttructure(please see the image)and it is a pity not having its solution

Comment: Having been here a while, you should know that the Math.SE community expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (Eg, *What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?*) In this case, since the sangaku diagram shown includes an "answer", providing a translation of that (and also the "expression"?) would be helpful to give answerers an indication of the level of complexity expected (and to let them check their work). BTW: Is it given/expected that the edges of the two lower equilateral triangles are collinear, or merely that the triangles share a vertex?

Comment: @Blue, I'VE POSTED THEPROBLEM AS I'VE SEEN IT IN THIS pHd tHESIS : https://www.academia.edu/30061089/_PhD_Thesis_Sangaku_A_Mathematical_Artistic_Religious_and_Diagrammatic_Examination.i THINK THE POROBLEM IS WILL POSED. THE RESTRICUONS SEEMS TO BE IN CONFICT.

Comment: @Blue. THE ANSWER GIVEN IN THE pHd THESIS DOESN'T HELP:

ANSWER: 答日乙圓径寸九分弐厘Answer: The diameter of otsu 乙is 6 sun 9 bu
毛弐絲有奇2 rin 8 mo 2 .

Comment: Assuming that the lower two triangles have collinear sides, and the upper two triangles have perpendicular sides, some coordinate bashing in *Mathematica* seems to confirm that, when the larger circle has diameter $12$, the smaller one has diameter $6.0937\ldots$. However, getting these values appears to require numerical methods, as the diameters themselves are encoded in degree-$6$ polynomials. ... A nice-ish intermediate result: if $O$ is the center of the outer circle, while $P$ and $Q$ are the bottom vertices of the lowest triangle, then $\tan\angle POQ=\frac23(3-\sqrt3)$.

Comment: @Blue, could you dhare the mathematica codem okease?

Comment: My work isn't yet in a presentable format. I'll see if I can make some time for this over the weekend.

Comment: @Blue, o, please, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to see the question re-opened. It turns out that the key degree-$6$ polynomial I mentioned factors into quadratics with appropriate finessing. (And there's a straightforward path to the relevant factor without having to consider the degree-$6$ polynomial at all.) So, the process is easier than my first pass would have me believe. The final result is still a bit of a mess to write down, though. I'm checking for a simplification I may have overlooked.

Comment: @Blue, I am very curious to see the details of your Mathemtica solution!

Comment: I'm interested in showing it, but I'm having trouble finding a "good" presentation of it. I'll keep looking. :)

Comment: This is the very first Problem presented in the mentioned thesis, p.20. There is also a Technique... @HumbertoJoséBortolossi didn't you see it? The Technique is: *Put the diameter of circle kō squared. Divide by three. Take the square root.
Obtain the diameter of otsu as required.* This signifies that the diameter of the small circle is $4\sqrt3,$ approx. $6.9282$ Hovewer, if the triangles are located as they look like (described by Blue ), this value is too large and cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear in the diagram, but I'm taking the lower two triangles to have collinear sides, and the upper to triangles to have perpendicular sides. (Luckily, the consequence of these assumptions matches the numerical value given in the problem.)

Let the bounding circle have center $O$ and radius $r$; let the triangles have side-length $2s$; let the upper triangles make a right angle at $D$, and define $d:=|OD|$; and let the target triangle have centers $P$ and $Q$ and radii $p$ and $q$, as shown.

[image]

Note that $P$ and $Q$ line on the bisector of the angles made by triangle sides at $D$.

From the figure at left above, we deduce without too much trouble that
$$r^2 = s^2\left(1^2+(\sqrt{3}+1)\right)^2=s^2(5+2\sqrt{3})$$
$$d^2 = s^2\left(1^2+(\sqrt{3}-1)\right)^2=s^2(5-2\sqrt{3})$$
$$\cos\angle ODE = -\frac{s}{d}(\sqrt{3}-1) \qquad \sin\angle ODE = \frac{s}{d}$$
Defining $\theta := \angle ODP = \angle ODE-105^\circ$ we can calculate
$$\cos\theta := \cos\angle ODE \cos 105^\circ + \sin\angle ODE \sin 105^\circ = \frac{s}{d}\cdot\frac{5-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
The tangencies of $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc Q$ imply
$$\begin{align}
|OP| &= r-p \qquad |DP| = p\csc45^\circ \\
|OQ| &= r-q \qquad |DQ| = q\csc75^\circ
\end{align}$$
so that applying the Law of Cosines to $\triangle ODP$ and $\triangle ODQ$ gives
$$\begin{align}
(r-p)^2 &= d^2 + p^2\csc^245^\circ - 2 d p \csc45^\circ \cos\theta \\
(r-q)^2 &= d^2 + q^2\csc^275^\circ + 2 d q \csc75^\circ \cos\theta
\end{align}$$
Solving these quadratics for $p$ and $q$ gives these positive roots:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{p}{s} &= \frac12 \left( \mu - 2\lambda 
+ \sqrt{2 (24 + 7\sqrt3 - 2\lambda\mu)}
\right) && = 1.649\ldots \\[4pt]
\frac{q}{s} &= (7+\sqrt{3})\left(
\nu - \lambda 
+ \sqrt{
   2 (3 \sqrt3 - \lambda\nu)} \right) && = 0.837\ldots \\[4pt]
\lambda &:= \sqrt{5+2\sqrt{3}} \qquad \mu := 5-\sqrt{3} \qquad \nu := 4-3\sqrt{3}
\end{align}$$

Thus, $q/p = 0.507\ldots$, so that for $p=12$, we have $q = 6.0937\ldots$. $\square$

---

If there are nicer forms of $p$ and $q$, then I'm not sure what they are. And yet, I suspect additional structure lurks in the configuration, since the legs of the right triangle with hypotenuse $d$ are
$$s = \frac{s\csc45^\circ}{\sqrt2} \qquad s(\sqrt{3}-1) =  \frac{s\csc75^\circ}{\sqrt2}$$